# How to echo text during SQL script execution in SQLPLUS

Tags: sql, oracle11g, sqlplus

I have a batch file which runs a SQL script in sqlplus and sends the output to a log file:

> sqlplus user/pw < RowCount.sql > RowCount.log

My log file contains this:

```
Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production

SQL> SQL> 
  COUNT(*)
----------
     0

SQL> 
  COUNT(*)
----------
     0
```

etc. but it's several thousand lines of output and therefore hard to determine which results belong to which statement.

I would like to add some formatting to the output, so that I may discern what happened. Either an echo of the executed statement or manually inserting some "echo" statements into the script would be fine. Ideally it would look something like this:

```
SQL> select(*) from TableA;
  COUNT(*)
----------
     0

SQL> select(*) from TableB;
  COUNT(*)
----------
     0
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can use `SET ECHO ON` in the beginning of your script to achieve that, however, you have to specify your script using `@` instead of `<` (also had to add `EXIT` at the end):

**test.sql**

```
SET ECHO ON

SELECT COUNT(1) FROM dual;

SELECT COUNT(1) FROM (SELECT 1 FROM dual UNION SELECT 2 FROM dual);

EXIT
```

**terminal**

```
sqlplus hr/oracle@orcl @/tmp/test.sql > /tmp/test.log
```

**test.log**

```
SQL> 
SQL> SELECT COUNT(1) FROM dual;

  COUNT(1)
----------
     1

SQL> 
SQL> SELECT COUNT(1) FROM (SELECT 1 FROM dual UNION SELECT 2 FROM dual);

  COUNT(1)
----------
     2

SQL> 
SQL> EXIT
```

Answer (score 57):

The **prompt** command will echo text to the output:

```
prompt A useful comment.
select(*) from TableA;
```

Will be displayed as:

```
SQL> A useful comment.
SQL> 
  COUNT(*)
----------
     0
```

Comment: Yes, but that makes you add that `prompt` before every query that you execute in your script. Anyway, still a possible solution, +1.

Answer (score 4):

You can change the name of the column, therefore instead of "COUNT(*)" you would have something meaningful.  You will have to update your "RowCount.sql" script for that.

For example:

```
SQL> select count(*) as RecordCountFromTableOne from TableOne;
```

Will be displayed as:

```
RecordCountFromTableOne
-----------------------
           0
```

If you want to have space in the title, you need to enclose it in double quotes

```
SQL> select count(*) as "Record Count From Table One" from TableOne;
```

Will be displayed as:

```
Record Count From Table One
---------------------------
            0
```